# what is the mean of \+ in the below code

Tags: prolog

I am analyzing the code of whether a number is prime or not i am not able to get the meaning of operator "\+" in prolog.(I am naive in prolog).

```
is_prime(2). is_prime(3).
is_prime(P) :- integer(P), P > 3, P mod 2 =\= 0, \+ has_factor(P,3).
has_factor(N,L) :- N mod L =:= 0.
has_factor(N,L) :- L * L < N, L2 is L + 2, has_factor(N,L2).
```

I have understand the other thing but not able to understand the meaning of "\+" in second line.

can anyone explain me the above?

Comment: If the answer helped you, please do click the tick to select it.

Comment: It mimics the symbol ⊬ (Unicode U+22AC DOES NOT PROVE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "not provable". So `\+ Thing` succeeds if `Thing` can't be proven.

There's a useful [dictionary of Prolog](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html). The negation section is what you're after.